# Substring using Regex?

Tags: regex, substring

I have a string which I know the contents are effectively fixed width.

I am using an application which only supports Regex and want to be able to only read the characters between 2 positions of the string.

Here is the String

```
1        CIR  3152885  N           SYS    151   16082016    135732     Appointment complete16082016
```

I want to only read the `3152885` part of the string which starts at character 15 and ends at character 21

Can you help me work this out. Once I do I can do it with this example, I will hopefully be able to apply the same method to extract other parts of the string.

The end goal is to read each part of the string into variables which I can then build into a `SQL INSERT`

Comment: `3152885` does not appear to start at position 15 of the sample string you gave us.  In any case, it would be easy to either regex or substring off thisi value.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: What have you tried? I get the feeling you tried something but aren't sharing it, or that you haven't done much research and want us to do it for you.

Comment: What language are you using? Is 15-21 consistent?

Comment: Try this `^\w+\s+\w+\s+(\d+)\s+`

Comment: In macro languages just use `substr()`. In C, use pointer arithmetic. If you have to use just regex, it's this `^.{14}(.{7})` and value is in group 1.. Keep counting for the next one, etc.. That's it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in fact, `3152885` was at the 15th position but the formating removed consecutive spaces

Comment: I had been using the Regex builder\tester on http://www.regextester.com/ to test different solutions I had found on the web with none working.

I had already tried `^.{14}(.{7})` but it selects everything from the beginning of the string up to the end of the number I want rather than just the number itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer

```
(?<=^.{14}).*?(?<=.{21})
```

Super excited about this as it is going to help me so much with parsing stupid fixed width flat files that an application my company uses.